# Expectation of proportion random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two random variable. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. We also have $f$ and $g$ are two continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is the following equation true?
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{f(X)}{g(Y)} \right] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[f(X)]}{\mathbb{E}[g(Y)]}$$

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: taking f,g as the identity and X, Y as uniform over [0,1], is an example that the above identity does not hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, we would write the expectation as $$E \left[ {f(X) \over g(Y)} \right]= E\left[ f(X) \right] E \left[{1 \over {g(Y)}} \right]$$